# AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropdown

I'm trying to use angularjs for dropdown with multiple selection. 
Using 1 of them it works great, but if I need 2 dropdown in the same form, it doesn't get initialized. Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/vUSPu/1221/, any kind soul could guide me on how to display 2 working dropdown? Thanks!

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">    
    <dropdown-multiselect pre-selected="member.roles" model="selected_items" options="roles"></dropdown-multiselect>


    <pre>selected roles = {{selected_items | json}}</pre>
</div>

<div ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="AppCtrl2">    
    <dropdown-multiselect pre-selected="member.roles" model="selected_items" options="roles"></dropdown-multiselect>


var app = angular.module('myApp', ['app.directives']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){                     
    $scope.roles = [
          {"id": 1, "name": "Manager", "assignable": true},
          {"id": 2, "name": "Developer", "assignable": true},
          {"id": 3, "name": "Reporter", "assignable": true}
    ];

    $scope.member = {roles: []};
    $scope.selected_items = [];
});

var app2 = angular.module('myApp2', ['app.directives']);

app2.controller('AppCtrl2', function($scope){                     
    $scope.roles = [
          {"id": 1, "name": "Manager", "assignable": true},
          {"id": 2, "name": "Developer", "assignable": true},
          {"id": 3, "name": "Reporter", "assignable": true}
    ];

    $scope.member = {roles: []};
    $scope.selected_items = [];
});

var app_directives = angular.module('app.directives', []);

app_directives.directive('dropdownMultiselect', function(){
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope:{           
            model: '=',
            options: '=',
            pre_selected: '=preSelected'
       },
       template: "<div class='btn-group' data-ng-class='{open: open}'>"+
        "<button class='btn btn-small'>Select</button>"+
                "<button class='btn btn-small dropdown-toggle' data-ng-click='open=!open;openDropdown()'><span class='caret'></span></button>"+
                "<ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownMenu'>" + 
                    "<li><a data-ng-click='selectAll()'><i class='icon-ok-sign'></i>  Check All</a></li>" +
                    "<li><a data-ng-click='deselectAll();'><i class='icon-remove-sign'></i>  Uncheck All</a></li>" +                    
                    "<li class='divider'></li>" +
                    "<li data-ng-repeat='option in options'> <a data-ng-click='setSelectedItem()'>{{option.name}}<span data-ng-class='isChecked(option.id)'></span></a></li>" +                                        
                "</ul>" +
            "</div>" ,
       controller: function($scope){

           $scope.openDropdown = function(){        
                    $scope.selected_items = [];
                    for(var i=0; i<$scope.pre_selected.length; i++){                        $scope.selected_items.push($scope.pre_selected[i].id);
                    }                                        
            };

            $scope.selectAll = function () {
                $scope.model = _.pluck($scope.options, 'id');
                console.log($scope.model);
            };            
            $scope.deselectAll = function() {
                $scope.model=[];
                console.log($scope.model);
            };
            $scope.setSelectedItem = function(){
                var id = this.option.id;
                if (_.contains($scope.model, id)) {
                    $scope.model = _.without($scope.model, id);
                } else {
                    $scope.model.push(id);
                }
                console.log($scope.model);
                return false;
            };
            $scope.isChecked = function (id) {                 
                if (_.contains($scope.model, id)) {
                    return 'icon-ok pull-right';
                }
                return false;
            };                                 
       }
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSFiddle example is slightly different from the code you provided. Which one is reflecting what you need?

**JSFiddle solution**

You are repeating the `ng-app="myApp"` so when the second code runs the AngularJS app instance for `myApp` has already been initialized. To solve that you can just remove that second initialization and put the second dropdown within the first (and only) `ng-app` scope.

**Code on question solution**

Assuming you want to have two different *applications* running on your document you need to start it manually as Angular will detect just the first one. Something like this:

```
<script>
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp', 'myApp2']);
</script>
```

Comment: Just found it that if I put it within the ng-app scope, it is able to initialize. However I would need them to be different division. Now I'm trying your code on question solution.

Comment: Do i need to have 2 directive module?

Comment: No you don't. The directive is a single reusable component so as long as you are injecting it on your app's dependencies you should be fine.

Comment: Then how do i differentiate it? i believe it will be called twice, under the $scope I will be able to differentiate it?

Comment: They are already different as the directive creates a scope for each component (look at the `console.log` how they show different data as you change the models).

Comment: Are you sure you want two different apps running? If they are part of the same form I believe you would want them under the same application. In this case you just need to go with JSFiddle solution and then use a different variable for `model="selected_items"` on the second dropdown